# Указатель на массив объектов класса

Tags: c++, ооп

Создаётся в классе `Logic` массив объектов класса `Players`

```
Players* players = new Players[10];
```

В классе main для доступа к игрокам сделано следующее

```
Logic *logic = new Logic();
logic->players[selectPlayer].getName();
```

Можно ли сделать указатель/ссылку типа `players`, которую можно писать вместо `logic->players`?
Т.е. писать вместо

```
logic->players[selectPlayer].getName();
```

это

```
players[selectPlayer].getName();
```

Comment: А почему бы, раз уж вы на C++ пишете, вам не использовать `vector` или  `array`? Это не упрощает запись, для этого надо действовать, как @Qwertiy советует, но получается более безопасно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Logic *logic = new Logic();
Players *&players = logic->players;
players[selectPlayer].getName();
```